# Background transparency for PDF/SVG

Tags: pdf, backgrounds, svg, transparency

I am using lua/xe/latex to generate a logo as a PDF and convert it to an SVG using pdf2svg for use on a web page.

I would like to have a transparent background for the PDF and SVG.

The transparent package seems to work only on text colours but not on the background. I have read that the TikZ/PDF suite will allow transparent backgrounds at

http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=697

and need to investigate that further.

Meanwhile, I thought I should find out if there is a simple and easy solution like:

```
\pagecolor{transparent}
```

that may be invoked with some package.

FWIW, I have previously gone down the road of converting the PDF to a PNG and adding transparency to the background colour(s) using the ImageMagick suite. I do not want to go down that path again: hence my attempt at generating an SVG logo.

Comment: It looks like the SVG obtained from pdf2svg already has a transparent background, at least for web page display. So it appears that my question was a non sequitur at least for web page display :-)

Answer (score 4):

(Originally posted as a comment by the OP chandra)

It looks like the SVG obtained from `pdf2svg` already has a transparent background, at least for web page display. So it appears that my question was a non sequitur at least for web page display :-)